# Azure function retry policies for multiple output bindings?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function which I want it to write to both an EventHub and EventGrid, and have some questions on the retry policies.

1. are there built in retry policies already in place? If one fails, does it try to write to it again? Or does it count as successful if only one of them has been written to?
2. Do I need to have custom retry code for eventhub and eventgrid, or are there extensions I can use for both? I believe there is one for EH, but could not find one for EG.

Answer (score 1):

**Event Hub:**

Retry policies is available for EventHub Triggered functions which are applicable in function level.
Check the below table to know about which triggers support retries and where its behavior is configured.

[image]

- When the Event Hubs-triggered function fails and raises an exception, the retry policies will be assessed.
- Then the policy assists the function runtime to re-run the failed execution until either it reaches the maximum number of retries or function executes successfully.
- In few rare situations, an execution will be re-tried more than the requested maximum number of retries.

> The current retry count will be stored in memory of the instance. The maximum retry count is a best effort, and When there is failure in Event Hubs, retry count re-set to zero, the trigger will be able to resume processing and retry the batch on a new instance.

You can configure the maximum number of times to let the function tries to execute before it fails using:
`[FixedDelayRetry(5, "00:00:10")]`.

- To use this, you need to install nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`.

**Reference:**

[Retry Policies for Event Hub Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#retry-policies)

**Event Grid:**

- There is no built-in retry policy for Event Grid however, it provides durable delivery.
- If there is any failure in event grid subscription, It retries delivery based on a fixed retry schedule and retry policy.
- Event Grid by default delivers one event at a time to the subscriber, it tries to deliver the message at least once for each identical subscription immediately.

**Retry Policies for Event Grid:**

- You can customize the retry policy when creating an event subscription by using the `Maximum number of attempts` and `Event time-to-live (TTL)` configurations.

1. **Maximum number of attempts**:  It's value must be between 1 and 30, default value is 30.
2. **TTL**: It's value must between 1 and 1440, default value is 1440 minutes.
   By default, Event Grid tries for 1440 minutes(1 day), or 30 times.

[image]

- If you set both Event time-to-live (TTL) and Maximum number of attempts in Event Grid,the event delivery will be dropped when it reaches any of the limits of the policy.
- You can set these values during creation of Event Grid subscription to let Event Grid try to deliver the event.

As per my research, there seems to be no extension available for Event Grid as we have for Event Hub.

**References:**

[Azure Event Grid delivery and retry - Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-policy)

[Dead letter and retry policies - Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery#set-retry-policy)